# how to kill long running aws s3 cli command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i have a long running aws s3 cp command

`aws s3 cp folder1/ s3://bucket/ --recursive`

can this command be terminated gracefully

can we pass TIMEOUT

`aws --TIMEOUT 1800 s3 cp ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for automation i was able to put a timeout like below

/usr/bin/timeout -s 1800 /usr/bin/aws s3 cp folder1/ s3://bucket/ --recursive

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't an option to terminate gracefully.